# what is the most efficient way to remove the duplicates BETWEEN the arrays, not WITHIN?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am NOT looking for the unique values within an array. I want to remove the elements, which are found in any other arrays. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'area': a, 'orDate': b, 'orNo': c})
    area      orDate  orNo
0    1.0  20160926.0  10.0
1    2.0  20160926.0  20.0
2    1.0  20160926.0  10.0
3    1.0  20160926.0  10.0
4    2.0  20160926.0  30.0
5    2.0  20160926.0  20.0
6    2.0  20160926.0  40.0
7    2.0  20160927.0  50.0
8    1.0  20160927.0  60.0
9    1.0  20160927.0  20.0
10   3.0  20160927.0  30.0
11   3.0  20160927.0  80.0
12   3.0  20160927.0  90.0
13   3.0  20160927.0  20.0
gb=df.groupby(['area','orDate'])['orNo'].unique().reset_index()
   area      orDate                      orNo
0   1.0  20160926.0                    [10.0]
1   1.0  20160927.0              [60.0, 20.0]
2   2.0  20160926.0        [20.0, 30.0, 40.0]
3   2.0  20160927.0                    [50.0]
4   3.0  20160927.0  [30.0, 80.0, 90.0, 20.0]
I want:
0   1.0  20160926.0                    [10.0]
1   1.0  20160927.0                    [60.0]
2   2.0  20160926.0                    [40.0]
3   2.0  20160927.0                    [50.0]
4   3.0  20160927.0              [80.0, 90.0]
orNo 20,30,40 are seen more than once. So should be deleted.
```

Comment: That's impossible. An array must have the same number of elements in each row and in each column

Comment: @user4421975 That's an object dtype array.

Comment: right. I edited my question.

Comment: BTW you have changed the question quite a bit as it went from arrays to a dataframe and you might have a better solution to directly go from `df`to desired output without even creating `gb`. One of the Pandas gurus might be able to help on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an almost* vectorized approach -

```
lens = np.array(map(len,arr))
vals = np.concatenate(arr)
unq,c = np.unique(vals,return_counts=1)
dup_vals = unq[c>1]
valid_mask = ~np.in1d(vals,dup_vals)
out_vals = vals[valid_mask]
cut_idx = valid_mask.cumsum()[lens.cumsum()-1]
out = np.split(out_vals,cut_idx)[:-1]
```

If you don't have access to one of the recent versions of NumPy that supports `return_counts` with `np.unique`, here's an alternative way to get `dup_vals` with `np.bincount`, assuming `non-negative` numbers in input array -

```
dup_vals = np.nonzero(np.bincount(vals)>1)[0]
```

Additionally, another way to get `cut_idx` is with `np.searchsorted` -

```
cut_idx = np.searchsorted(np.nonzero(valid_mask)[0],lens.cumsum())
```

*: Almost because of the use of `map` at the first step, but being used there to get just the lengths of each list in input array, it should have minimal effect on performance.

---

Going loopy way, here's another one, once you have `dup_vals`, with a loop comprehension -

```
out = [np.setdiff1d(i,dup_vals) for i in arr]
```

Comment: I get TypeError, unexpected keyword argument 'return_counts'... else looks like nice solution. I tried to solve it, but was so far stuck with a lot of for loops.

Comment: @Dr.V Added an alternative for that.

Comment: Thank you @Divakar. is arr same as gb['orNo'] in my example?

Comment: @P.J Looks like it.

Comment: @Divakar I got this error:     dup_vals = np.nonzero(np.bincount(vals)>1)[0]
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: @P.J I guess you need to convert to int type with something like : `gb['orNo'].values.astype(int)` for use as `arr`.

Comment: @P.J Sorry I meant do `vals = np.concatenate(arr).astype(int)` keeping rest of the code the same.

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. I got this error:     cut_idx = valid_mask.cumsum()[lens.cumsum()-1]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'map' and 'int'

Comment: @P.J Did you try with `vals = np.concatenate(arr).astype(int)` and changing nothing else in the proposed code?

Comment: @Divakar I only did this change: vals = np.concatenate(arr).astype(int) Error is:     cut_idx = valid_mask.cumsum()[lens.cumsum()-1]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'map' and 'int'

Comment: @P.J I am not sure at this point. You could try : `arr=gb['orNo'].values`. Other than that I am out of ideas.

Comment: @Divakar Thank you

Comment: @Divakar I just changed the way to produce lens to :lens=zeros(gb['orNo'].size)
for i in range(0,gb['orNo'].size):
    lens[i]=gb['orNo'][i].size                                 
lens=lens.astype(int)                                     It worked. Thanks again. Your answer was very smart and quick.

Comment: @P.J Awesome! Relieved to hear that.